# Using PHP Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I have been searching websites to try and get a handle on using PHP namespaces, but they all seem quite vague but what they're trying to do is easy to understand!

My question is: I have a file called `people.php` and in it is defined class called `people`. If I create another file called `managers.php` in the same folder can I define a class again called `people` which extends the original `people` class but in the namespace of `managers`, if so do I have to 'include' the original `people.php` and if so do I put the include after the writing: `namespace managers`?

Comment: One thing to take note that namespaces in PHP does not reflect your directory structure. You have to manually map your directory structure with your namespace names.

Comment: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/) would be a great resource to clear everything you need to know regarding PHP namespaces.

Answer (score 32):

Namespaces are a way to group your related classes in packages. What you describe could best be put under a single namespace like

```
<?php // people.php
namespace com\example\johnslibrary\people;
abstract class People {

}
```

and then

```
<?php // manager.php
namespace com\example\johnslibrary\people;
require_once 'path/to/People.php'; // can better use autoloading though
class Manager extends People {

}
```

because a Manager is a subclass of People, so there is not much of a reason to put them into their own namespace. They are specialized People.

If you want to Managers to be in their own namespace, you can do so, but have to use the fully qualified name when using the `extends` keyword, e.g.

```
<?php // manager.php
namespace com\example\johnslibrary\managers;
require_once 'path/to/People.php';
class Manager extends \com\example\johnslibrary\people\People {

}
```

or import the People class first

```
<?php // manager.php
namespace com\example\johnslibrary\managers;
use com\example\johnslibrary\People as People;
require_once 'path/to/People.php';
class Manager extends People {

}
```

[See the PHP Manual on Namespaces for extensive documentation.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Answer (score 4):

```
// people.php
<?php
namespace People;

class People {}


// managers.php
<?php
namespace Managers;

require_once __DIR__.'/people.php';

class People extends \People\People {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have old PHP Class and i need to use it in new PHP file as for example:`index.php` has to use `iClass.php`. But before using the OLD iClass.php i have to modify it as below, so that i can use it in index.php.

**iClass.php:**

```
namespace ic;
class iClass {
  public static function callMeFromClass() {
    echo 'OK - you have called me!';
    exit;
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
namespace inex;
require_once 'iClass.php';
use ic\iClass;
iClass::callMeFromClass();
```